# Shopping Cart Rule based on configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

Is it possible to set up a shopping cart rule as follows:

if any combination of 3 'child' products of a configurable product are added to the cart, add a discount.

ie: if we're talking about t-shirts, the customer could add 2 red and 1 blue, or 3 blue and still get the discount.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to use the following rule:
[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

You may change the 'Attribute Set is Clothing' condition to suitable one.
Also, I have chosen the applying this rule to the items with qty 3 or more. 
Does it solve your problem?

Comment: maybe linked https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219885/magento-1-x-shopping-cart-rules-apply-discount-action-not-working-for-parent-co

Answer (score 0):

Ideally one would just like to set:

3 or more of the parent/configurable product

(so one does not have to meddle at all with the children)